# How to convert posts as products with there categories?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on woocommerce product Convert.I am converting post into woocommerce products on click of import button.Convert is working fine but i have created same categories as in posts and i need to import products in the same categories as posts. for example i have categories in posts.

Style - main cat
  Men -- Sub Cat
    Clothing -- Men Sub Cat
       Shirt
    Belts
  Women -- Sub cat
    Clothing -- Women Sub Cat
        Top
    Purse

And i have created same categories in woocommerce. Now when i am importing posts then if a post is in Women Clothing category then the imported product should go to Women Clothing category.Products should import according to categories and sub categories.This is my code to convert post as products.

```
foreach ($items as $post) { 
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );                
    $getpostid = $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT post_id 
        FROM " . $wpdb->prefix ."postmeta AS pm 
        INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."posts AS p 
            ON p.ID=pm.post_id 
        WHERE pm.`meta_key` = 'admitted_goods_id' 
        AND pm.`meta_value` ='".$post->ID."' 
        AND p.post_status='publish' 
    ");

    foreach($getpostid as $k=>$postdata) {
        $postId              = $postdata->post_id;
        $admited_goodsId[$k] = get_post_meta($postId, "admitted_goods_id", true);
    }

    if($post->ID==$admited_goodsId[0]) { 
        echo "Updated";
    } else { 
        //echo "Insert";        
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_title'   =>  $post->post_title,
            'post_content' => $post->post_content,
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
            'post_type'    => "product",
        ) );

        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'external', 'product_type' ); 
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' ); 
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'no' ); 
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id',$post_thumbnail_id);
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'admit_ds_id',$post->ID);
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock'); 
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_button_text','Buy Now');
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_brand', $pdata->vendor );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_model', $pdata->model );  

        $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'adm_category', array("fields" => "all"));
        foreach($term_list as $term) {
            wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $term->name, 'product_cat', false );
        }

        $getOtherdata = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix ."admitad_product_data where post_id=".$post->ID); 

        foreach($getOtherdata as $pdata) { 
            //echo $pdata->price;
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $pdata->old_price );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', $pdata->price );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_url',$pdata->url);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $pdata->price );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_currencyId', $pdata->currencyId );
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There were two errors in your code that I fixed please check below:

```
<?php 

foreach ($items as $post) {

        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );

        $getpostid = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix ."postmeta as pm inner join ".$wpdb->prefix."posts as p on p.ID=pm.post_id WHERE pm.`meta_key` = 'admitted_goods_id' AND pm.`meta_value` ='".$post->ID."' and p.post_status='publish' ");
        foreach($getpostid as $k=>$postdata) 
        {
            $postId = $postdata->post_id;
            $admited_goodsId[$k] = get_post_meta($postId, "admitted_goods_id", true);
        } 

        if($post->ID==$admited_goodsId[0])
        { 
            echo "Updated";


        }else 
        { 
            //echo "Insert"; 

            $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_title' =>  $post->post_title,
            'post_content' => $post->post_content,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => "product",
            ) );  
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'external', 'product_type' ); 
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' ); 
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'no' ); 
            update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$post_thumbnail_id);
            update_post_meta($post_id,'admit_ds_id',$post->ID);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock'); 
            update_post_meta($post_id,'_button_text','Buy Now');
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_brand', $pdata->vendor );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_model', $pdata->model );  





            //$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'adm_category', array("fields" => "all"));
            $term_list = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );
            // $term_list variable is an array containing IDs of all the post categories

            // foreach($term_list as $term) 
            // {  

            //     wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $term->name, 'product_cat', false );

            // } 
            // wp_set_post_term can't be used to update Product Category/Terms since this function can only be used to update Terms of native post type not custom post type. In order to update Terms of custom post type which is Products in our case we need to use wp_set_object_terms function.




            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $term_list, 'product_cat' );




            $getOtherdata = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix ."admitad_product_data where post_id=".$post->ID); 
            foreach($getOtherdata as $pdata)
            { 
                //echo $pdata->price;
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $pdata->old_price );
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', $pdata->price );
                update_post_meta($post_id,'_product_url',$pdata->url);
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $pdata->price );
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_currencyId', $pdata->currencyId );
            }   

    }   
}  

?>
```

Comment: wp_get_post_categories() return empty array.I am using custom post type

Comment: $term_list = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'admitad_category' ); I have used this to get term list. It is inserting product categroies but if men and women cat have accessory cat and in accessory have bag cat then it insert men category bag into women category bags products.

Comment: Ok try using wp_set_object_terms functions instead of wp_set_post_terms and supply it with an array of Category IDs.